# Parsing an Incongruous String Post Domain Name String

Tags: php, arrays

```
/one_path/some_page.php?var1=value1&var2=value2&var3=value3
```

Suppose I'm given something like the above. Not just the query variable string, but the path that comes before it.

I want to parse the above string so that it creates an array that's like

```
array('var1' => 'value1', 'var2' => 'value2', 'var3' => 'value3')
```

I can easily do this, but I'm wondering what is the 'best' way to do this, so the code is short and clean; I'm a bit of a perfectionist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[parse_str()](http://php.net/parse_str) is helpful once you have extracted the query string from the path.  Assuming the URI is well formed, you could split them using something like this:

```
list($path, $query) = explode('?', $uri, 2);
parse_str($query, $query_parsed);

var_dump($query_parsed);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function for parsing query string into array **[parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)**.